# SharePoint List Advanced mode JSON Syntax for CC email to

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a simple SharePoint list of email template to send an email to our customers.

I have the basic JSON format that I got from here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#create-clickable-actions but I am trying to send an email based on the SharePoint field values. For example: if I click the email button on line1 the email will be send to abcde@company.com; test@sharepoint.com and CC abcde@company.com; test@sharepoint.com and the message will be the MessageBody column. everything works fine but I just don't know the syntax code for CC email.

Here is my SP List:

[image]

I used Single line text for both EmailTo and CC column.

and here is the Syntax I used:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "padding-right": "50px"
      },
      "txtContent": "@currentField.title"
    },
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Mail",
        "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
        "href": {
          "operator": "+",
          "operands": [
            "mailto:",
            "[$EmailTo]",
            "?subject=",
            "[$Title]",
            "&body=",
            "Hello,",
            "\r\n",
            "\r\n",
            "[$MessageBody]",
            "\r\n",
            "\r\n",
            "\r\n",
            "\r\n",
            "Thank you,",
            "\r\n",
            "\r\n",
            "\r\n \r\n",
            "\r\n \r\n"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Email sample that shows using the code syntax above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add CC part like `cc=abc@xyz.com`. Try using this JSON:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "span",
        "style": {
          "padding-right": "50px"
        },
        "txtContent": "@currentField.title"
      },
      {
        "elmType": "a",
        "attributes": {
          "iconName": "Mail",
          "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
          "href": {
            "operator": "+",
            "operands": [
              "mailto:",
              "[$EmailTo]",
              "?cc=",
              "[$CC]",
              "&subject=",
              "[$Title]",
              "&body=",
              "Hello,",
              "\r\n",
              "\r\n",
              "[$MessageBody]",
              "\r\n",
              "\r\n",
              "\r\n",
              "\r\n",
              "Thank you,",
              "\r\n",
              "\r\n",
              "\r\n \r\n",
              "\r\n \r\n"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Where `CC` in `[$CC]` is **internal name** of CC column. You can get the exact internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.